# is there any way can i use the Django for existing database? if yes how to use models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am working on already existing data on relational database. Now question is that how to build models and how to update the tables with new data coming from user (technically django forms)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django natively supports creating models for and working with existing data. From the documentation:

[Integrating Django with a legacy database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/legacy-databases/)

Django will still need to create several of its own tables, but will adapt to use your existing tables. From the doc, you can auto-create models like this:

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

You'll need to determine whether you want to manage updates to the table structure, but that's getting into details that will be specific to your project.